# SQL Server database : Change Table Value from texbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to change the value of a column in a SQL Server table from filtered by 2 others columns. But it returns error: Incorrect syntax ",". Here is code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Server.ini") + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + "lin2world" + ";" + "User ID=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("User.ini") + ";" + "Password=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Password.ini");

        string sql = "UPDATE user_item SET amount='" + textBox3.Text + "'WHERE char_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' ,item_type='" + textBox2.Text + "' ";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        connection.Open();

        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "user_item");
        connection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Item Amount Changed");
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: read about SQL Injection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Server.ini") + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + "lin2world" + ";" + "User ID=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("User.ini") + ";" + "Password=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Password.ini");
    string sql = "UPDATE user_item SET amount='" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE char_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND item_type='" + textBox2.Text + "' ";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    connection.Open();
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "user_item");
    connection.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Item Amount Changed");
}
```

Two mistakes - Space before `WHERE` and missing `AND` in `WHERE` clause

Raj

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a space before `WHERE`.

And you have a comma where you want to use `AND`.

Change like this:

```
string sql = "UPDATE user_item SET amount='" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE char_id='" + 
                        textBox1.Text + "' AND item_type='" + textBox2.Text + "' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

The sql where conditions will be either combined by using `AND` or `OR` so you need to replace the comma ( `textBox1.Text + "' ,item_type='" +`) with the wanted expression.

Also it would be much better with regard to [`sql injection`](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=7XgpUtAyhpi1BsP5gfAG&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&bvm=bv.51773540,d.Yms), to use [`command parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the values beeing compared and updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space between ' and `where`. Also, you are doing an update and populating a data set? Are you just looking to do an update or are you trying to get data as well?

You should look to use `string.Format()` here to make it more readable. Also, consider [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) as you are leaving yourself open to [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Better still, ditch the dynamic sql and replace with a [stored procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15403/Calling-Stored-procedures-in-ADO-NET).

[Tutorial on String.Format()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format)

If you're not using the dataset, then use ExecuteNonQuery()

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Server.ini") + ";" +
                              "Initial Catalog=" + "lin2world" + ";" + "User ID=" +
                              System.IO.File.ReadAllText("User.ini") + ";" + "Password=" +
                              System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Password.ini");

    string sql = string.Format("UPDATE user_item SET amount='{0}' WHERE char_id='{1}' AND item_type='{2}'",
                               textBox3.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Item Amount Changed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "UPDATE user_item SET amount='" + textBox3.Text + "'WHERE char_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' ,item_type='" + textBox2.Text + "' ";
```

here

`,item_type=`  ',' should be "and" or "or"

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend you not to use this format:

```
sql = "UPDATE user_item SET amount='" + textBox3.Text + "'WHERE char_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' ,item_type='" + textBox2.Text + "' ";
```

instead, you should use:

```
sql = String.format("UPDATE user_item SET amount=%d WHERE char_id=\'%s\' and item_type=\'%s\'",textBox3.Text,textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);
```

This form is much more clear to avoid errors.